# maximum data that can be sent through a port-socket

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, network-programming

i have implemented a program which takes input from client, performs operation on server and writes the data to the client. `ls` command is what i have chosen for example.

Now my doubt is,

1) what if the input is very huge in bytes??

2) what is the maximum data that can be sent through a socket port??

**client.c**

```
int main()
{
        FILE *fp;
        int servfd, clifd;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
        struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
        int cliaddr_len;
        char str[4096], clientip[16];
        int n;

        servfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(servfd < 0)
        {
                perror("socket");
                exit(5);
        }

        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVPORT);
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVIP);

        if(bind(servfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
        {
                perror("bind");
                exit(0);
        }

        listen(servfd, 5);

        printf("Server is waiting for client connection.....\n");

        while(1)
        {
                cliaddr_len=sizeof(cliaddr);
                clifd = accept(servfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &cliaddr_len);

                strcpy(clientip, inet_ntoa(cliaddr.sin_addr));
                printf("Client connected: %s\n", clientip);

                if(fork() == 0)
                {
                        close(servfd);
                        while(1)
                        {
                                n = read(clifd, str, sizeof(str));
                                str[n] = 0;

                                if(strcmp(str, "end") == 0)
                                {
                                        printf("\nclient(%s) is ending session and server is waiting for new connections\n\n", clientip);
                                        break;
                                }
                                else if (strcmp(str, "ls") == 0) {
                                        system("ls >> temp.txt");
                                        fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
                                        fread(str, 1, 500, fp);
                                        remove("temp.txt");
                                        }
                                else
                                        printf("Received from client(%s): %s\n", clientip, str);

                                write(clifd, str, strlen(str));
                        }
                        close(clifd);
                        exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                        close(clifd);
                }
        }
}
```

**server.c**

```
int main()
{
        int sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
        char str[500];
        int n;

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVPORT);
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVIP);

        if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
        {
                printf("Could not connect to server: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
        }

        while(1)
        {
                printf("Enter message: ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]", str);
                write(sockfd, str, strlen(str));

                if(strcmp(str, "end") == 0)
                        break;

                n  = read(sockfd, str, sizeof(str));
                str[n] = 0;
                printf("Read from server: %s\n", str);
        }

        close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: I think that everyone who is programming anything using sockets HAS to read [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your question no 1. the huge data is broken in many packets & then sent packet by packet its done by OS internally. & the one packet size depends on your system OS(you can change it.It is called MTU maximum transfer unit).

& for your question no 2. the data send by a socket port may be infinite coz as long as u wish to send data it will send. there is no limit.!!!

Comment: I have been sending many huge files using socket recently and I find it disconnecting automatically after about 7 gb for some reason. I don't know why but I think that there is a limit. Also, on another device, it was getting disconnected on it's own after 20 gb so I think it varies from device to device. However, whenever it disconnects, I tell it to reconnect. In this way, I can send as much data as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Q: What if the input is very huge in bytes?? What is the maximum data that can be sent through a socket port??

A: There is no limit on the size of a TCP/IP stream.  In theory, you could send and receive an infinite number of bytes.

... HOWEVER ...

1) The receiver must *never* assume is will ever get all the bytes at once, in a single read.  You must *always* read socket data in a loop, reading as much at a time as you wish, and appending it to the data you've already read.

2) You can send a "large" amount of data at once, but the OS will buffer it behind your back.

3) Even then, there's an OS limit.  For example, here the maximum send buffer size is 1 048 576 bytes.:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc2%2Fcpp_send.html

If you need to send more, you must send() in a loop.

PS:

As Anish recommended, *definitely* check out Beej's Guide to Network programming:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/